# Facebook Graph Api - Event

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any methods/ways to create a Facebook event without using graph api?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to automate it, if that is your question. You need to go to www.facebook.com and create an Event as User or Page.

Comment: So am i right to say that the only way to create a facebook event is on the facebook website itself right?